# Distance metric for comparing two rankings of different length with partial overlap

Tags: correlation, ranking, distance

Suppose I have two competing ways to rank:

```
 1. Bob     Bob
 2. Alice   Sam
 3. Tom     Alice
 4. Sam     .
```

The rankings may have some overlap (like Bob, Sam, and Alice above), and may be of different lengths (method two likes a fourth place).

Is there a way to define how discordant these are (in terms of position, composition, and cardinality)? I am aware of some solutions in cases where the lists are mere permutations, but not the general case. I would even appreciate the terms for this problem.

Is there a way to test if the difference is significant (comparing method 1 and method 2 on a set of queries, i.e., on paired data)?

Comment: I guess this could depend on context, that is, why isn't Tom ranked in the second list? He couldn't compete that day? Maybe just leave him out ... but other contexts might need other solutions. I doubt this question can be answered in the abstract!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Tom could be eliminated for criteria not used by the first algorithm.